# Compile dlib for Android on Ubuntu

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ubuntu, dlib

I'm trying to compile dlib for Android. My SO is Ubuntu 20.04. I followed this tutorial from https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android

I downloaded Android-NDK version r14b and unzipped it at /opt. When I run `python3 build.py` command, I get this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /opt/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++: not found
/bin/sh: 1: /opt/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++: not found
make: *** [/opt/android-ndk-r14b/build/core/build-binary.mk:530: obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/android_dlib/jni_imageutils.o] Error 127
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/bin/sh: 1: /opt/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++: not found
make: *** [/opt/android-ndk-r14b/build/core/build-binary.mk:530: obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/android_dlib/jni_pedestrian_det.o] Error 127
make: *** [/opt/android-ndk-r14b/build/core/build-binary.mk:530: obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/android_dlib/jni_face_det.o] Error 127
Build Error
```

Inspecting `/opt/android-ndk-r14b`, there is no `linux-x86_64` under `prebuild` folder. The only directory there is `darwin-x86_64`.

I also tried with `android-ndk-r21d`, but I got another error:

```
/opt/android-ndk-r21d/build/core/add-application.mk:178: *** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Build Error
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into this, https://github.com/Luca96/dlib-for-android/blob/master/setup.sh. I did not try on linux but if there are problems the link below could give some hints.

I used the `powershell script` with some modifications from the repo above and used `dlib master` from github to compile on windows. It copies files to given Android Studio folder when done. Latest modified script here, https://github.com/quickgrid/Setup-Guide/blob/master/dlib-android-setup.ps1.